# simple WYSWYG publishing system

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg, markdown, publishing, textile

I'm constantly dealing with the same problem in many of my different projects:

How to deal with making content publishable in the most simple way possible by people with low/no IT skills.

The easiest way is shove something like TinyMCE (think wordpress) into their hands, the usual route because people are more or less accustomed to it.

The problem is... some part of me is inevitably reduced to agony when I see some of the html that gets inserted either by the html editor or pasted in from Word or wherever else like muddy shoes being dragged into an otherwise clean house.  I know that errant HTML can be constrained but even with it reduced to it's most basic form, it still manages to produce mayhem and inconsistencies between users.

I would love to force users to learn Markdown or Textile (ala stackoverflow) but I usually lose this battle and I have yet to see an editor that can compete with any of the HTML editors in terms of low barrier to entry.  I have yet to see one that is all contained inside one window (WYSIWYG), most or all? use one to type and one to display which most users just don't get.

I also often use Zemanta, as much for it's ease of use as to reduce the risk of users uploading copyrighted material but it also relies on HTML for it's widgets unless you want to roll your own using their API directly.  But without HTML how do you account for multiple images throughout a document and deal with their positioning?

I'm curious to see how others have solved this problem because every solution I have created I constantly re-evaluate afterwards and find lacking. Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem is not the editors, it's that the users don't understand the purpose of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like to use [Aloah](http://www.aloha-editor.org/) as my go to WYSIWYG Editor. It is more lightweight than TinyMCE and leaves less possibilities for the user to introduce ugly HTML.

There is also [WYMEditor](http://www.wymeditor.org/) (What you see is what you mean). Its looks are not as nice as Aloah's, but it certainly works in keeping people from creating bad HTML.

In opposition to jgauffin I think it is possible to enforce the creation of clean HTML by inexperienced users. The problem is more that TinyMCE and the likes want to provide layout features which are autonomous from the implementing pages style definitions.